# "Source file could not be read" error when exporting database

Tags: github, phpmyadmin

I made a draft of a Wordpress website on localhost using XAMPP.  I made a database for it using MySQL.  I'm ready to upload to BlueHost.  I understand that means I need to save the database as a single .sql or .sql.zip file.

I keep getting the "...\UAywaMh-.sql.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read" when I try to turn the database into an .sql file that I can upload to BlueHost.  BlueHost help says that the problem is not on their end.  I've tried it in Firefox and Chrome.  Chrome says "couldn't download."

I did leave the "New template" and "Existing template" fields blank.  Is that it?

I know the name of the database I created and I was able to find it easily in https://localhost/phpmyadmin/  I don't think I have the wrong one.

How do I fix this so I can get my website live?  Thanks!

UPDATE: On GitHub, someone described the same problem and said that patch #17447 fixes it, but I can't find the patch anywhere. https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/17445

UPDATE: A GitHubber responded!  Turns out the answer is to update phpMyAdmin to version 5.20 or later!  The first time I did this, I couldn't log in, but the trick is to copy over the config.something file!

Comment: So dont zip the file, just make a simple .sql file from your locahost database

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.  That is what produces the error message "...\UAywaMh-.sql.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read."

Comment: You only get `.part`'s when you are using a compressed file!

Comment: That is new information for me.  So how do I NOT use a compressed file?  I'm in phpMyAdmin.  I selected my database, clicked on "Export" and hit "Go." I never told it to compress anything. Where do I select "no compressed files"?  Also I keep seeing that the file name before .sql.part keeps changing.  I don't know if that's important.

Comment: So dont use the default options! Under METHOD select CUSTOM, then under FORMAT select SQL. Then under OUTPUT, select COMPRESSION: NONE

Comment: HOORAY!  I will do just that!  ...  Okay, "COMPRESSION" was already set to "NONE."  Okay, I got the exact same error message: "6spTIZv_.sql.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read."  Tried it again in Chrome...  Yeah, same results: "Couldn't download - Network issue."

Comment: Are you getting this from the EXPORT or the IMPORT?

Comment: I'm clicking on EXPORT. "Exporting tables from [its name] database" in my localhost phpMyAdmin

Comment: ok, so why did you ask the BlueHost guys if it was a problem on their server if you have not even completed the EXPORT from your own local system. Something here does not GEL??

Comment: You do realise you have to EXPORT from your local system, copy the exported file to the BlueHost server (FTP probably) and then IMPORT that file on the BlueHost system. Right?

Comment: I asked the BlueHost agents because I'm a first-timer at this.  I figured that the BlueHost guys would at least be able to tell me what file was wanted, what folder it might be in, or what file ending it had.  In fact, it was a BlueHost person who explained that I had to export the file first and that "export the file" is how you say "CREATE the .sql file, which is what's wanted." It's only that I keep getting this "source file could nto be read" message when I attempt to do so.

Comment: Yes, ok, its just weird that you are getting a file read error when you are doing the EXPORT which is basically an Output only function

Comment: Please show me ALL the error message, in case there is somethig useful in there you are not registering

Comment: Thanks, I will!  On Chrome, the message is "Couldn't download - network issue." When I try the exact same thing on Firefox, I get (hang in whilst I do it again) three lines.  Line one: "Downloading C:\Users\[thats's me]\Downloads\QQkgJcrQ.sql.part." Line two: C:\Users\[thats's me]\Downloads\QQkgJcrQ.sql.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read." Line three: "Try again later, or contact the server administrator."  ...do I need to log in differently or do something with these "permissions" I keep hearing about?

Comment: On GitHub, someone described the same problem: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/17445  They say there is a patch, #17447, that will fix it, but I can't find a link to any downloadable item on this page or the other discussion thread.

Comment: Thats not anything to do with running phpMyAdmin, that sounds like when you are uploading the export file to the hosted server

Comment: As long as you're running phpMyAdmin 5.2.0, don't worry about the patch as the patch would only be needed for older versions (but there's not really a good reason to use 5.1.x anymore). That could be the cause of the network issue. On the other hand, how big is your database? You could also try using the SaveDir feature (https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_SaveDir) to write the file to the server then use SFTP, SCP, or whatever other means you have available to download the file separately. That could help.

Comment: Yup!  Updating phpMyAdmin from the 5.1.8 that came with XAMPP to 5.2 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this so anyone in the future can find the solution.

The problem ended up being fixed by https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/17445 which was fixed in phpMyAdmin 5.1.4 and 5.2.0. It seems there was a related problem in PHP https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/8218 that caused download issues with some browsers.

Upgrading to the latest phpMyAdmin release was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

From following instruction my problem is solved, I have export the db file.

Goto XAMP Control Pannel
Open > Shell
//Write following command in shell

## mysqldump -u [root] -p [BD_Name] > [backup_file_Name].sql

> > hit enter

Enter password:

This will ecport your file and filename.sql will save in your xammp folder